# Controller's action with name "list" showing 404 for the custom module

Tags: magento2, controllers, 404

I am using Magento 2 version 2.2.2

I have a simple custom module and right now for the testing it only has `Index` controller. The problem is all actions for this `Index` controller works fine but somehow the action name `List` is showing "404 Not Found".

Custom module files are as below.
At `app/code/Vky/` then

[image]

**Vky/JustTesting/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vky_JustTesting',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Vky/JustTesting/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vky_JustTesting" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**Vky/JustTesting/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="justtesting" frontName="justtesting">
            <module name="Vky_JustTesting" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Vky/JustTesting/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vky\JustTesting\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r("Index Action");die((__FILE__).'-->'.(__FUNCTION__).'--Line('. (__LINE__).')');
    }
}
```

**Vky/JustTesting/Controller/Index/List.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vky\JustTesting\Controller\Index;

class List extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r("List Action");die((__FILE__).'-->'.(__FUNCTION__).'--Line('. (__LINE__).')');
    }
}
```

At frontend.

`http://127.0.0.1/magento222/justtesting/index/index` - Works
`http://127.0.0.1/magento222/justtesting/index/list` - Not working

To make sure I created other actions also like `View`,`Save`, `Delete`

`http://127.0.0.1/magento222/justtesting/index/view` - Works
`http://127.0.0.1/magento222/justtesting/index/save` - Works
`http://127.0.0.1/magento222/justtesting/index/delete` - Works

Then I thought Let me try with `List01.php`

**Vky/JustTesting/Controller/Index/List01.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vky\JustTesting\Controller\Index;

class List01 extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r("List01 Action");die((__FILE__).'-->'.(__FUNCTION__).'--Line('. (__LINE__).')');
    }
}
```

And `http://127.0.0.1/magento222/justtesting/index/list01` - Works

I have tried all this.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

remove `var/cache` and `var/page_cache` folder. But nothing is helping.

Why is the list action not working? 
Is there any restriction to use action name?
Am I missing something?
Something wrong with my project? But I have tried this in another project also and the same problem.

> If it's because of this.

There is some reserved word in PHP. `List` is one of them. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php
Then why I can use it in Magento 1. `http://127.0.0.1/magento1936/justtesting/index/list` - Works in Magento 1.

I am just hoping for some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reserved word in PHP. **List** is one of them. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

> You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to confusion.

Comment: Maybe. But Then Why I can use it in Magento 1. For example, `http://127.0.0.1/magento1936/justtesting/index/list` is working at Magento 1.

Comment: It works in Magento 1 because the functions of controllers ending with the word **Action** and the name of the class is something like this **Vky_JustTesting_IndexController**

Comment: Yes, my friend. It makes sense now.

Comment: If you think that my answer is the correct. Please, mark it as valid

Comment: Yes, it is valid. I was just trying to make the same for "New" and "Break". Both are reserved word. So It won't work. "New01" and "Break01" Works. Thank you for your help.